# What is the most beginner-friendly book for information geometry?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, references, information-geometry

**Question:** What is the most beginner-friendly book for information geometry?

The book:

- Amari and Nagaoka, *Methods of Information Geometry*,

is often mentioned as a reference for information geometry.

However, Amari has also written several other books about the subject, at least two of which also seem like they are oriented towards beginners:

- Amari, *Differential Geometric Methods in Statistics*.
- Amari, *Information Geometry and its Applications*.

These two books by different authors also seem targeted towards beginners:

- Arwini, Dodson, *Information Geometry*.
- Murray, *Differential Geometry and Statistics*.

In case Amari is one of those geniuses who has so much to say about their ideas that they can't possibly explain it concisely/simply/straightforwardly, perhaps it might be better to start with something written secondhand by another author.

I also have access to these other books, which seem like they are more advanced monographs, but I am not really certain, so I am mentioning them here anyway:

- Cencov, *Statistical Decision Rules and Optimal Inference*.
- Kass, Vos, *Geometrical Foundations of Asymptotic Inference*.

[This thesis](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~lebanon/pub/thesis/thesis.pdf) (later published as a [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3659682020)) also seems relevant:

- Lebanon, *Riemannian Geometry and Statistical Machine Learning*.

What I often do is read a lot of books and get only a little out of each (because I don't spend any time thinking about any of them or doing any of the problems).

However, this time, instead of reading eight books, which would be exhausting anyway, I want to focus on one and only one but get a lot out of it.

Thus any informed suggestions or recommendations would be useful/helpful.

**Note:** Also there is the issue of there being other applications to statistics of differential geometry than just the field of information geometry itself, per se, although I am not knowledgeable about this distinction at all. All of the above books seem to reference Riemannian metrics and exponential families of random variables in some way, so I assume they are about information geometry, but if that is not the case for one of them, that would make for a simple and easy elimination criterion.

Answer (score 9):

I also think these books are quite hard to read at the first place too (but I'm an applied guy). For me, it was simpler to start with scattered material/tutorial/applications using bits of IG such as: [Pattern learning and recognition on statistical manifolds: An information-geometric review](http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/Labo/Frank.Nielsen/FN-SIMBAD2013.pdf)
.

Comment: Thanks @mic! This reference was really useful. I definitely recommend reading it. 
Pattern learning and recognition on statistical manifolds: An information-geometric review .

Comment: this is exactly what I needed!